# Pandas Python Data Frame: Adding a column depending on the rest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames and I want to join them using a "key" that I am going to create.
My data frames are of the form:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3  
   1        240     31-02-16  
   2        350     25-03-16  
   3        100     31-03-16  
   4        500     13-02-16
```

and I want to create a new column as:

`str(Column1) + "-" + str(Column2) + "-" + str(Column3)`

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpliest is cast to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) each column:

```
df['new'] = df.Column1.astype(str) + "_" + 
            df.Column2.astype(str) + "_" + 
            df.Column3.astype(str)
print (df)
   Column1  Column2   Column3             new
0        1      240  31-02-16  1_240_31-02-16
1        2      350  25-03-16  2_350_25-03-16
2        3      100  31-03-16  3_100_31-03-16
3        4      500  13-02-16  4_500_13-02-16
```

Solution with apply:

```
df['new']=df[['Column1','Column2','Column3']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
print (df)
   Column1  Column2   Column3             new
0        1      240  31-02-16  1_240_31-02-16
1        2      350  25-03-16  2_350_25-03-16
2        3      100  31-03-16  3_100_31-03-16
3        4      500  13-02-16  4_500_13-02-16
```